# std::nullptr_t arguments in variadic functions

Tags: c++, c++11

So apparently a `std::nullptr_t` argument is converted to a null pointer of type `void *` (Section 5.2.2/7 of N3337) when passed without a parameter (via `...`). This means that to properly pass a null `char *` pointer, for example, a cast is still needed:

> some_variadic_function("a", "b", "c", (const char *) std::nullptr);

since there is no guarantee that a null `void *` has the same bit pattern as a null `char *`. Correct?

This also means that there is no advantage to `std::nullptr` over `0` in such cases, except perhaps for clarity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You ask:

> since there is no guarantee that a null `void *` has the same bit pattern as a null `char *`. Correct?

Well, actually, that guarantee does exist, Deduplicator's answer already shows where the standard requires this. But that is not relevant to your question.

Passing `void *` to a variadic function, and accessing it using `va_arg` as `char *`, is specifically allowed as a special exception.

C++11:

> **18.10 Other runtime support [support.runtime]**
>
> 1 Headers `<csetjmp>` (nonlocal jumps), `<csignal>` (signal handling), `<cstdalign>` (alignment), `<cstdarg>` (variable arguments), `<cstdbool>` (`__bool_true_false_are_defined`).  (runtime environment
>   `getenv()`, `system()`), and `<ctime>` (system clock `clock()`, `time()`) provide further compatibility with C code.
>
> 2 The contents of these headers are the same as the Standard C library headers `<setjmp.h>`, `<signal.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and `<time.h>`, respectively, with the following
>   changes:
>
> [... nothing about `va_arg`]

C99:

> **7.15.1.1 The `va_arg` macro**
>
> [...] If there is no actual next argument, or if *type* is not compatible with the type of the actual next argument (as promoted according to the default argument promotions), the behavior is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> -- one type is a signed integer type, the other type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> -- one type is pointer to void and the other is a pointer to a character type.

However, this does mean that in other cases where two types `T1` and `T2` have the same representation and alignment requirements, the behaviour is undefined if `T1` is passed to a variadic function, and it is retrieved as `T2`.

An example of this: passing `(void *) 0` and accessing it as `char *`, is allowed, passing `(void *) 0` and accessing it as `unsigned char *` is also allowed, but passing `(char *) 0` and accessing it as `unsigned char *` is *not* allowed. If a compiler is capable of inlining calls to variadic functions, and optimises based on the strict requirements of the standard, such mismatches could break badly.

> This also means that there is no advantage to `std::nullptr` over `0` in such cases, except perhaps for clarity.

I would definitely *not* use `nullptr` without casting it, even though in this one special case it is valid. It is far too hard to see that it is valid. And if a cast is included anyway, `(char *) 0` is just as clear as a null pointer value.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong. One of the few guarantees are that a `char*` has the same size and representation as the corresponding `void*`.

> #### 3.9.2 Compound Types §4
>
> A pointer to cv-qualified (3.9.3) or cv-unqualified void can be used to point to objects of unknown type.
>   Such a pointer shall be able to hold any object pointer. **An object of type cv `void*` shall have the same
>   representation and alignment requirements as cv `char*`.**

Edit: Looks like [this answer by hvd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23375539/3204551) is better, showing a few more traps specific to the variadic function part of the question.

Comment: Thanks. I found a reference for C, though not yet for C++.

Comment: Got the reference finally.

Comment: So the cast is still needed if not some `char *` type.

Comment: Right, there are few guarantees regarding pointer representation, and too few for the general T* case.

Comment: The reasoning in this answer is wrong. Having the same representation and alignment requirements isn't enough to allow this. The actual reason it is valid is because the C++ standard defines `va_arg` as C's `va_arg`, and the C standard makes a special exception for 1) signedness mismatch, 2) pointer to `void` vs. pointer to character type. It *doesn't* allow `va_arg` of the wrong type in other cases, even in other cases where the types have the same representation and alignment requirements.

Comment: Examples of other types with the same representation and alignment requirements are pointers to different structure types, or two enumeration types with the same underlying type. This can easily break badly if a call to a variadic function gets inlined, and the optimiser doesn't understand the bogus `va_arg` uses.

Comment: @hvd Please, add an answer detailling your different reasoning. Anyway, will think on your comment.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make both of these answers as "the answer".